# How to return handlerinput.responsebuilder inside a function using node js for Alexa Skill

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, return, alexa-skills-kit

I have been struck as to how to return handlerinput.responsebuilder to speak the value stored inside the variable of a function for my Alexa Skill. I am using ask-sdk-core node js for building my Alexa Skill. The function I am using is as below. Please help me in solving this.

```
function callback(out)
{
    var jsonurl=out;   
    console.log(jsonurl)

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak(jsonurl)
                .getResponse();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not included `handlerInput` in callback function params. Try doing like below :

```
  handle(handlerInput) {
     var out = ""

        getJSON(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            if (data !== "ERROR") {
                 var speechOutput = data
                   out = speechOutput;
             }
         });

     function getJSON(callback) 
     {
            //As I don't know what result might be So I am giving some string value.
              var result = 'Thank you !!';
             if (result!=='') {
                 callback(result);
              } else {
                  callback("ERROR");
              }
     }
        return callback(out,handlerInput)
  }

};

function callback(out, handlerInput)
{

  const jsonurl=out;
  console.log(jsonurl)


  return handlerInput.responseBuilder
         .speak(jsonurl)
         .getResponse();

}
```

The above one worked perfectly fine for me and I am getting the given result to the `out variable`. I think there might be a problem in the result you are getting from the URL can you check that one weather it is string or object.

Comment: Thanks but my issue is the out variable is stored inside another function which I need to pass to the callback function. How to get that value from that function?

Comment: In my above code, I get ``out`` variable as ``hi`` because I am sending from handle function to callback function. And can you also update the code where you are facing the problem?

Comment: Can you please refer my code and provide a solution to this.

Comment: Its not speaking the value in out variable its returning empty as declared var out="", Even if passed say var out="Thank You!!" as suggested by you. The out value is passing as null only irrespective of my url parsing. Please help.

Comment: Can you please provide me the solution

Comment: Thanks was able to get the value after proper debugging. However can you please tell how to play audio stored in a variable like this  in the response .addAudioPlayerPlayDirective('REPLACE_ALL', jsonurl, stream.token, 0, null, stream.metadata); //where jsonurl holds the .mp3 https url

Comment: I did not get your question can you please create another thread or explain what do you want clearly.

Comment: return handlerInput.responseBuilder
         .speak(`Playing Now ${calm_audio_name}`)
         .addAudioPlayerPlayDirective('REPLACE_ALL', 'jsonurl', 1, 0, null, null);

Comment: In the above response builder jsonurl holds the url which contains the audio mp3 to be played but its not playing it. However if I hard code the url in place of jsonurl its playing the audio. Did you understand the issue?

Comment: Please note if I do console.log(jsonurl) I am able to get the url printed. I want this .mp3 extension url to be played. Hope you have understood.

Comment: For example var jsonurl='https://xyzsong.mp3'. Its not playing it If I send jsonurl

Comment: Check if you are getting a response like this (http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bUomHwqywi?indent=2) when you keep a jsonurl variable.

Comment: No, In url field I am getting variable name like this  "url": "jsonurl" instead of the value its holding. How to fix this?

Comment: can show me the code so that I can look for errors.

Comment: I have added the code below. Please do refer and reply Sir